# I accidentally gave the wrong person a bounty, who can I contact to undo?

Tags: support, bounties

I was reading a comment that I assumed to be from the person who I intended to give the bounty to and accidentally clicked +50 for the wrong answer. Sorry I was in the middle of doing something else and not really paying attention.

I would like to undo this, who can I contact to make the request? The question is [How can I transform this linq expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19031493/304832).

Comment: No can do and this is a dupe, let me see..

Comment: Dupe of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194654/152859

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - But that's a dupe too

Comment: @Sha, maybe a moderator could refund the bounty so the questioner can perform the process again (hopefully choosing the right answer this time :) ?

Comment: @Cybȫʁgϟ37 true but it also contains very relevant comments and answer which also answer this question.

Comment: Next time pay attention. Now morally right thing to do would be set another bounty, with reason "reward existing answer", and this time do it right...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi nope, moderator and even dev can't refund bounty *that was already awarded*. It's like undoing upvotes. (by mod or dev)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd technically devs can, it's just an entry in DB like anything else. They just won't. And I agree, removing so much rep from someone's account seems bad. Undoing upvotes is done at regular basis ("serial voting reversed" anyone?). It's a matter of rules, not technicalities.

Comment: @Sha, [are you sure of that?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124530/164403)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi hmm.. let me check again

Comment: @Sha, [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27103/164403) from our fearless co-founder mentions a Remove / Refund Bounty menu, but indeed does not say if it applies to awarded bounties. That would make sense IMHO, though.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'm still quite sure it only applies to *active* bounty. But not 100% anymore.

Comment: Pretty sure that when awarding a bounty a message box comes up that makes it clear this action cannot be undone.

Comment: @sha - Wow... so you can offer a bounty, get an answer, award the bounty, then delete the question (provided there were no upvoted answers) to get your rep back? Sounds like a loop hole to me...

Comment: @Lix yes, actually [I already reported this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145329/152859) with my own experiment.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145333/152859): *as moderator, on questions where the bounty is already assigned, I don't see any link that allows me to refund the bounty* :-)

Comment: @Sha, excellent. Thank you for your sound research :)

Comment: Was other answer helpful to you? You asked op to delete his answer just because your mistake ? Well that is not a good behavior

Comment: @NullPoiиteя, I am not sure if the answer was helpful as I have not tried it. The original answerer answered my question BEFORE I decided to award the bounty. I decided to offer the bounty JUST BECAUSE the person answered it very quickly before I was even ABLE to offer a bounty. This bounty was for a gesture of gratitude after the answer had been accepted, not to try and entice answers. And no, I do not actually know the person who I want to award the bounty to. I considered it a very difficult question and was very thankful, thats all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stuff happens, no biggie. Leave a comment for the intended recipient to explain what happened. Most folks will probably be just fine with that.

If you feel so inclined you could follow a suggestion from the comments and post another bounty, award that one to the right person.

Let mods and SO devs spend their precious time on more pressing issues.

Comment: While I thought this is the right and best answer, now I think this time that was the best way what the OP chose: to ask the owner of the answer with the awarded bounty to temporally delete the answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone and sorry for the dupe, I don't use meta often. User has kindly deleted his answer. Do I have to post another question to ask that the bounty be refunded, or should I just wait?

Comment: @danludwig I don't think a bounty can be refunded at all, as mentioned by ShaWizDowArd in a comment to the question. You could try of course, by flagging your question for moderator attention, but wouldn't get my hopes up.

Comment: I am the author of the question that was erroneously awarded the bounty.  I deleted my original answer, as requested, and the bounty reputation points were removed from my account.  I then submitted a slightly-altered copy of the original answer so as to not trigger any duplicate detection.  It now appears my original answer has been undeleted (though not by me), and the points returned.  I look rather silly having two nearly identical answers side by side.  Anyone here know who reactivated my original answer and why?  I'd like to know which answer to delete.

Comment: I wonder if a moderator undeleted this? Shouldn't there be a log of activity? Could someone have done this just to avoid having to refund the bounty? It's not like I want the points back, I just want to give them to someone else.

Comment: @MikeStrobel I along with 2 other 20k+ undelete your answer because I think its not fair to ask to delete answer just because that got awarded bounty mistakenly ... i think flag would be the way to go